# Force close by error java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use methods on my activity class to shorten my onCreate method.
But When I'm trying my app I got force close!

Activity Class (Main):

```
package ir.TeenStudio.ActivitiesManagement;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity {

    public static SQLiteDatabase ActivitiesListDatabase;

    private SlidingMenu slidingMenu;
    private ActivitiesExpandableListAdapter activitiesListViewAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> groupsList;
    private HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> childsList;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> todayChildsList;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> tomarrowChildsList;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> futureChildsList;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> oneDayChildsList;

    private ExpandableListView mylist;

    private TextView DayTextView;
    private TextView MonthTextView;
    private TextView YearTextView;

    private Button MainActivity;
    private Button ListActivity;
    private Button Setting;
    private Button Contact;
    private Button Information;

    private ImageButton Menu;
    private ImageButton Add;

    private Typeface Rezvan;
    private Typeface DroidNaskh;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        slidingMenu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        activitiesListViewAdapter = new ActivitiesExpandableListAdapter(Main.this, groupsList, childsList);
        groupsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        childsList = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>>();
        todayChildsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        tomarrowChildsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        futureChildsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        oneDayChildsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        mylist = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.activitiesListView);

        DayTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.day);
        MonthTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.month);
        YearTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.year);

        MainActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_main_activity);
        ListActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_lists_activity);
        Setting = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_setting);
        Contact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_contact);
        Information = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_info);

        Menu = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.menu_button);
        Add = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.add_button);

        Rezvan = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/rezvan.ttf");
        DroidNaskh = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/droid_naskh.ttf");

        // Sliding Menu
        setSlidingMenu();

        //TypoGraphy
        setLayoutTypoGraphy();

        //LayoutProgramming
        setTime();
        setButtonsEvent();

        //Creating Database
        try {
            final String path = Environment.getDataDirectory() +"/data/" + getPackageName() + "/ActivitiesList.db";
            ActivitiesListDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
            String query ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Content(";
            query += "Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,";
            query += "Description TEXT,";
            query += "AddLocation INTEGER,";
            query += "Location TEXT,";
            query += "AddDate INTEGER,";
            query += "DateYear INTEGER,";
            query += "DateMonth INTEGER,";
            query += "DateDay INTEGER,";
            query += "AddHour INTEGER,";
            query += "Hour INTEGER,";
            query += "Minutes INTEGER,";
            query += "AddAlarm INTEGER,";
            query += "AlarmTime INTEGER,";
            query += "AddSpecial INTEGER)";
            ActivitiesListDatabase.execSQL(query);
            Log.d("Database", "Database Created");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Database", "Database Error");
        }

        //Receive Data From Database
        receiveDataFromDatabase();

        //Sending Data to ListView
        mylist.setAdapter(activitiesListViewAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        receiveDataFromDatabase();
        activitiesListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void setLayoutTypoGraphy() {
        DayTextView.setTypeface(Rezvan);
        MonthTextView.setTypeface(Rezvan);
        YearTextView.setTypeface(Rezvan);
        MainActivity.setTypeface(DroidNaskh);
        ListActivity.setTypeface(DroidNaskh);
        Setting.setTypeface(DroidNaskh);
        Contact.setTypeface(DroidNaskh);
        Information.setTypeface(DroidNaskh);
    }

    public void setTime() {
        DayTextView.setText(ir.TeenStudio.ActivitiesManagement.ShamsiCalendar.getDay());
        YearTextView.setText(ir.TeenStudio.ActivitiesManagement.ShamsiCalendar.getYear());
        int solarMonth = Integer.parseInt(ir.TeenStudio.ActivitiesManagement.ShamsiCalendar.getMonth());
        switch (solarMonth) {
        case 1:
            MonthTextView.setText("فروردین");
            break;
        case 2:
            MonthTextView.setText("اردیبهشت");
            break;
        case 3:
            MonthTextView.setText("خرداد");
            break;
        case 4:
            MonthTextView.setText("تیر");
            break;
        case 5:
            MonthTextView.setText("مرداد");
            break;
        case 6:
            MonthTextView.setText("شهریور");
            break;
        case 7:
            MonthTextView.setText("مهر");
            break;
        case 8:
            MonthTextView.setText("آبان");
            break;
        case 9:
            MonthTextView.setText("آذر");
            break;
        case 10:
            MonthTextView.setText("دی");
            break;
        case 11:
            MonthTextView.setText("بهمن");
            break;
        case 12:
            MonthTextView.setText("اسفند");
            break;
        }
    }

    public void receiveDataFromDatabase() {
        groupsList.clear();
        childsList.clear();
        todayChildsList.clear();
        tomarrowChildsList.clear();
        futureChildsList.clear();
        oneDayChildsList.clear();

        groupsList.add("امروز");
        groupsList.add("فردا");
        groupsList.add("آینده");
        groupsList.add("یه روز");

        Cursor cr = ActivitiesListDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Content", null);

        if (cr.moveToFirst()) {

            do {

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("Description", cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("Description")));
                map.put("AddDate", cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("AddDate")));
                map.put("AddLocation", cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("AddLocation")));
                map.put("Location", cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("Location")));
                map.put("DateYear", cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("DateYear")));
                map.put("DateMonth", cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("DateMonth")));
                map.put("DateDay", cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("DateDay")));
                map.put("AddHour", cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("AddHour")));
                map.put("Hour", cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("Hour")));
                map.put("Minutes", cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("Minutes")));
                map.put("AddAlarm", cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("AddAlarm")));
                map.put("AlarmTime", cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("AlarmTime")));
                map.put("AddSpecial", cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("AddSpecial")));

                if (Integer.parseInt(cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("AddDate")))==1) {

                    if(Integer.parseInt(cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("DateYear")))==Integer.parseInt(ir.TeenStudio.ActivitiesManagement.ShamsiCalendar.getYear())
                            &&Integer.parseInt(cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("DateMonth")))==Integer.parseInt(ir.TeenStudio.ActivitiesManagement.ShamsiCalendar.getMonth())
                            &&Integer.parseInt(cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("DateDay")))==Integer.parseInt(ir.TeenStudio.ActivitiesManagement.ShamsiCalendar.getDay())){
                        todayChildsList.add(map);
                    }
                    else if (Integer.parseInt(cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("DateYear")))==Integer.parseInt(ir.TeenStudio.ActivitiesManagement.ShamsiCalendar.getYear())
                            &&Integer.parseInt(cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("DateMonth")))==Integer.parseInt(ir.TeenStudio.ActivitiesManagement.ShamsiCalendar.getMonth())
                            &&Integer.parseInt(cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("DateDay")))==(Integer.parseInt(ir.TeenStudio.ActivitiesManagement.ShamsiCalendar.getDay()))+1) {
                        tomarrowChildsList.add(map);
                    }
                    else {
                        futureChildsList.add(map);
                    }

                } else oneDayChildsList.add(map);

            } while (cr.moveToNext());

        }

        childsList.put(groupsList.get(0), todayChildsList);
        childsList.put(groupsList.get(1), tomarrowChildsList);
        childsList.put(groupsList.get(2), futureChildsList);
        childsList.put(groupsList.get(3), oneDayChildsList);
    }

    public void setSlidingMenu() {
        slidingMenu.setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
        slidingMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        slidingMenu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.menu_shadow);
        slidingMenu.setShadowWidth(30);
        slidingMenu.setFadeDegree(1.0f);
        slidingMenu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        DisplayMetrics display = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int width = display.widthPixels; 
        int menu_width = width - width / 3;
        if (menu_width < 100) {
            menu_width = 100;
        }
        slidingMenu.setBehindWidth(menu_width);
        slidingMenu.setMenu(R.layout.main_right);
    }

    public void setButtonsEvent() {
        OnClickListener ButtonsEvents = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.menu_button:
                        slidingMenu.toggle();
                        break;
                    case R.id.add_button:
                        Intent popUpAddItemDialogActivity = new Intent(Main.this, AddItem.class);
                        startActivity(popUpAddItemDialogActivity);
                        break;
                    case R.id.button_main_activity:
                        //Start main activity
                        break;
                    case R.id.button_lists_activity:
                        //Start lists activity
                        break;
                    case R.id.button_setting:
                        //Start setting
                        break;
                    case R.id.button_contact:
                        //Start contact activity
                        break;
                    case R.id.button_info:
                        //Start info activity
                        break;
                    default:
                    break;
                }

            }
        };
        Menu.setOnClickListener(ButtonsEvents);
        Add.setOnClickListener(ButtonsEvents);
    }
}
```

And this is my Manifest Code:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ir.TeenStudio.ActivitiesManagement"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/name_application"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="ir.TeenStudio.ActivitiesManagement.Splash"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ir.TeenStudio.ActivitiesManagement.Main" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        </activity>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" android:name="AddItem"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Log

```
08-24 22:10:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(2144): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-24 22:10:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(2144): Process: ir.TeenStudio.ActivitiesManagement, PID: 2144
08-24 22:10:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(2144): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ir.TeenStudio.ActivitiesManagement/ir.TeenStudio.ActivitiesManagement.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-24 22:10:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
08-24 22:10:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
08-24 22:10:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-24 22:10:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
08-24 22:10:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-24 22:10:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-24 22:10:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-24 22:10:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-24 22:10:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-24 22:10:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-24 22:10:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-24 22:10:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-24 22:10:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(2144): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-24 22:10:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at ir.TeenStudio.ActivitiesManagement.Main.setLayoutTypoGraphy(Main.java:140)
08-24 22:10:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at ir.TeenStudio.ActivitiesManagement.Main.onCreate(Main.java:91)
08-24 22:10:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
08-24 22:10:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-24 22:10:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
08-24 22:10:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     ... 11 more
```

Any Idea to solve this problem?

Comment: The force close was caused by the getAssets() call in line 53. You may want to put the getAssests() calls for the Typeface inititializations into onCreate() method.

Comment: I try this but app force close again by same error!

Comment: Please post the stack trace for the error now that you've made the change that hfann suggested.

Comment: stack trace errors uptaded plz help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Force close was caused by the `getAssets()` call outside activity methods.So intialize `Typeface` i.e. `getAssets()` in `onCreate` method,So change

```
 //Typography
    Typeface Rezvan = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/rezvan.ttf");
    Typeface DroidNaskh = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/droid_naskh.ttf");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

to

```
Typeface Rezvan,DroidNaskh;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

//Typography
    Rezvan = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/rezvan.ttf");
    DroidNaskh = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/droid_naskh.ttf");
```

Comment: I try this but app force close again by same error!

Comment: Is the problem in "private" code befor introduce buttons, typeface ... ?